# UWP App fails to post to a web service as multipart/form-data with digest authentication

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml, windows-10-mobile

When trying to post to a web service as multipart/form-data with digest authentication. It is failing with the following error  'System.Net.CredentialCache' is not supported for property 'Credentials'.

Using the below code to send credentials:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) asHttpWebRequest;
string formDataBoundary = String.Format("----------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());
string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary;
byte[] formData = GetMultipartFormData(parameters, formDataBoundary);

if (httpWebRequest == null)
{
    thrownewNullReferenceException("request is not a http request");
}

// Set up the request properties. 
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = contentType;
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = newCookieContainer();
var credentialCache = newCredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(
    newUri("http://someurl.com"), // request url's host
    "Digest",  // authentication type 
    newNetworkCredential(username, password) // credentials 
);
httpWebRequest.Credentials = credentialCache;
```

Comment: I tested your code with the fake requestUrl = http://someurl.com, and username = abc, password = abc, I can't reproduce your problem both on local machine and mobile emulator. And I can't find any problem in your code, strange thing.

Comment: Yes, I tested it in an UWP app.

Comment: ca you try this url "http://services.carlocale.com"

Comment: Tested again with this url, again no such error occurred. I think your error is not related to the url.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT changed the services to use post with application/ json made it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the services to use post with application/json instead and that solved it.

> var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, new
>   StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));